# Converting name-value pair into Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long list of name-value pairs in Python 3 that represent a single row from a database. Since the number of attributes is fairly large per row, I'm wondering if there is a faster or more pythonic way to convert this into a dict than the following:

```
name_value_pairs = [{'Name':'id', 'Value':1}, {'Name':'age', 'Value':22}]
for pair in name_value_pairs:
    result[pair['Name']] = pair['Value']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
result = dict( (item['Name'], item['Value']) for item in name_value_pairs)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! This also worked for me:

`result = {item['Name']: item['Value'] for item in name_value_pairs}`

Is this equivalent and is one more preferred than the other for Python 3?

Comment: Your version (with the braces) seems more common nowadays, so you can just use that if you like. There will be no difference in performance between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the *newer* dictionary comprehension syntax:

```
{item['Name']: item['Value'] for item in name_value_pairs}
```

as already mentioned in the comments by @instabrite.

It's been available [since Python 2.7 (2010)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#implementation) and is faster. Some profiling:

1. Using the `dict()` constructor: `dict( (item['Name'], item['Value']) for item in name_value_pairs)`

   ```
   >>> import timeit
   >>> timeit.timeit("dict( (item['Name'], item['Value']) for item in name_value_pairs)",
   ...               setup="name_value_pairs = [{'Name':'id', 'Value':1}, {'Name':'age', 'Value':22}]")
   0.6748202270264301
   ```
2. Using dict comprehensions: `{item['Name']: item['Value'] for item in name_value_pairs}`

   ```
   >>> timeit.timeit("{item['Name']: item['Value'] for item in name_value_pairs}",
   ...               setup="name_value_pairs = [{'Name':'id', 'Value':1}, {'Name':'age', 'Value':22}]")
   0.2638828816925525
   ```

As you can see, the dict comprehension is 2.5x faster. And imho, more Pythonic <del>and more readable</del>.